# FFMPEG: create a transparent background with lavfi?

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, subtitle

I can create a transparent background using lavfi by setting colorkey - but that gives problems with edges around fonts, etc.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080:color=0xff0000 
-an -vf "ass=test.ass,colorkey=0xff0000:0.5:0.5,format=yuva420p" 
-c:v png -t "00:01:40.544" -threads 0 "video.mov" -stats
```

How can I set the background to just transparent without resorting to colorkey?

Comment: `color=0xff0000@0.5,format=rgba` where `@0.5` is the opacity ranging from fully transparent (0.0) to completely opaque (1.0).

Answer (score 7):

Actually, @aergistal was almost there, but everything needed to be wrapped in one filter line, instead of two.

In other words, if you want to generate a transparent background, you have to specify the `format` filter already during the creation of the input – you cannot add it later.

So my winning combination was:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f lavfi -i 
"color=color=black@0.0:size=1920x1080,format=rgba,
subtitles=test.ass:alpha=1" -c:v png 
-t "00:01:00.000" -threads 0 "video.mov" -stats
```